# Establishing an Inequality and Possible Circular Reasoning.

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Let $0<\varepsilon \ll \delta$. Fix $\delta$. For any $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, I can deduce that $$1<\frac{\log n_k}{(1+\delta)^{k-k_0}\log n_{k_0}}<1+\frac{\log7}{\delta\log n_{k_0}}$$

Therefore, I write $(*)\,\log n_{k}<A_\delta(1+\delta)^{k-k_0}\log n_{k_0}.$

I ***really*** want to have $k_0$ large enough so that $$(**)\,\frac{1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\delta}}{A_\delta(1+\varepsilon)}\ge 1.$$ Is this possible? My intuition says *yes* since $(*)$ gives us some freedom on the choice of $A_\delta$ where it can be less than $1$; I.e., since $\log n_k<(1+\delta)^{k-k_0}\log n_{k_0}$, there are positive numbers $\lambda<1$ for which $\log n_k<\lambda(1+\delta)^{k-k_0}\log n_{k_0}$.

If this is true, can I choose $k_0$ large enough so that $(*)$ and $(**)$ are both satisfied, or is that circular?

Comment: [closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242300) (should have been linked in the question to avoid unnecessary duplication of efforts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant $\log n_k$ on the left of ($*$), you have $A_\delta>1$, so the expression on ($**$) is always $<1$.